# As a young person in his early 20s, when should I start thinking about buying a house?

Tags: mortgage, savings, first-time-home-buyer

I am saving up whenever I can for my future house downpayment, but I don't really have goals like :

- Have $X when I'm Y years old
- Buy a house at age Z

Are there good guidelines to have? Goals? What would you recommend? Or is it just a question of need rather than capability to pay?

I'm working full time as a web developer, so I have consistent income.

Comment: Need/want is definitely a factor.  In particular, a major consideration is how long you would plan to live in a house if you bought it.

Comment: Difficult to mark it as such from the Android app, but I think this could be closed ax duplicate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to consider when making the decision to buy a house. More so for a single person. Let's start with that. Are you now in an area that you are committed to? Or would you live anyplace? You fall in love, and your partner has a job that has great opportunity, but in a different state. That move can cost you nearly 8% of the home price. More if the price has fallen and you need to take the loss into account. 
That said, how does your current living expense compare with the expense of the home you'd consider? This is pretty localized.

Some areas have rent that's high compared to buying, other areas are just the opposite. I've seen duplexes that after a downpayment would have a rent that basically buys the house for you and lets you live rent and mortgage free.

If I were you, I'd first fill in the blank, "I'd really like a house instead of renting because _______" If this leads you to look for a house, that's fine. If you only answer that you always thought it was the next step in ones life at your age Or that it's a good investment, I'd reconsider.

Comment: Why should being a good investment not be a good reason (if it actually is one)? It's definitely localized, but when we ran the numbers, it definitely seemed to make sense financially, so we did (but exactly as you described, I'm very glad I *didn't* buy a place I was thinking about the previous year, by myself, as a year later I met someone, we moved in together, and it would've stunk if I'd just bought a place elsewhere the previous year.

Comment: By that line, I meant "because you heard that buying your own home in your 20's is a good long term investment." In other words, an uninformed decision. For the way OP phrased the question, I was afraid that might be the case, as if it were similar to "when should I start depositing to my 401(k)?"